# Bluetooth keyboard navigation for toolbar going into loop on android 9

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar

Android Bluetooth Keyboard navigation for Toolbar going into loop on android 9 it is working fine below android 9.

Issue is  when we press first time TAB key of bluetooth keyboard then focus on the 3 line of navigation drawer, When we press TAB again then focus on the Home text/label then again we press the TAB key then focus on notification icon up to here is fine but when we press TAB key again then focus should be on the home page container content like profile icon or refresh icon but it goes to whole Toolbar which I have attached screen shot below for reference. From that place it is going to loop like Whole toolbar,Nav 3 line then Home label then notification icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_back"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back_60"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_activity"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: how did you fix this issue?

Comment: raised bug on this with google and they are working on it still. Ticket URL https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141576457

Comment: were you able to get any solution?

Comment: @SAIR I raised incident but, haven't got any update on that from google team. I did not get chance to check on post android-9 version. You can check in latest android version does they resolve or not . It was know issue at that time. on android 9.

Comment: we got it working. posted an answer. hope it might help

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple things that you can consider

In API 26 [android:keyboardNavigationCluster](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:keyboardNavigationCluster) is introduced which keeps the focus locked to group of View. `AppBar/ToolBar` kind of use this property.

**Solution:**

1: hitting the key combinations Cmd+Tab (on Mac) or Ctrl+Tab (on Windows) will let you jump the navigation cluster and you will be able to navigate to `ToolBar` and screen content (there might be exception cases).

**How to unblock ?**

you can set the following attributes of Toolbar to false in the xml

```
android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
android:keyboardNavigationCluster="false"
```

or programatically

```
touchscreenBlocksFocus = false
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    isKeyboardNavigationCluster = false
}
```